# Place objects only on vertical/horizontal surface

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arkit

How, using ARKit for Unity, C#, can I make it so that the object can be placed only on vertical or only on the horizontal surface?

Can I control which angle of the surface is acceptable for placing an object on it?

Answer (score 1):

This stuff is pretty available on the official ARKit documentation. Nevertheless, Vertical surface support has not been added yet, but you can specify that you want objects placed horizontally.